# Why does glmnet standardisation only scale X?

Tags: r, statistics, glmnet

I've been reading about the impact of standardizing in `glmnet`. It's my understanding that when we set standardize==TRUE, then we center and scale the predictors to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1. However, in the `glmnet:::glmnet.path` function, which is used internally to fit the model, the following code exists:

```
   if (intercept) {
        xm <- meansd$mean
    }
    else {
        xm <- rep(0, times = nvars)
    }
    if (standardize) {
        xs <- meansd$sd
    }
    else {
        xs <- rep(1, times = nvars)
    }
```

So it seems to be that the data $X$ is only scaled when standardize=TRUE, and is centered only when we also have an intercept. Why is this?

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question than a programming question. It might be more at home at stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also this:

```r
    # return coefficients to original scale (because of x standardization)
    beta <- beta / xs
    a0 <- a0 - colSums(beta * xm)
```

which is meant to show that even if you choose to scale, then you'd need to return things to the right scale after fitting. But you want these operations not to alter anything, if you choose to *not* scale, hence they are not `TRUE`/`FALSE` but vectors that satisfy this piece of code (no op, because `xs` is `ones`, and `xm` is `zeros`), and also work for the `scale` function, as it accepts numerics as well.